# Java Applet Security External Domain

Tags: java, security, applet

I would like to use my own java ftp uploader between my servers however I can not figure out what is causing the connection issue. I looked at java.policy in target server. I have signed the jar files myself.

My applet is working fine in Eclipse or under the same domain, but when I try to connect from a different URL it gets stuck at

```
ftp.connect(this.host,2121);

ftp.setRemoteVerificationEnabled(true);
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode();
ftp.login(username, password);
```

Comment: Well here are my findings so far local eclipse to file server works, local host to file server does not work, file server to file server works if the firewall was the problem wouldn't fail on eclipse to file server ?

Comment: turned off local firewall (osx 10.6) still the same.